# How to create a CSV file from an existing file with a certain date range as the conditional

Tags: python, csv

I am new to programming and I'm trying to work with a very big file that keeps crashing Excel. I don't really need to work with the data in Python but just want to create a new file with what I need. The file is a list of corporations and I want to get all of them that were registered in 2020.

The excel file contains 34 columns (counting 0-34). The last column (34) is the one that contains the date registered.

```
import csv

with open('Business_Entities_in_Colorado.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    with open('New_File.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

        for line in csv_reader:
            if '2020' in line[34]:
                csv_writer.writerow((line),)
            else:
                print('Not found.')
```

I'm stuck on this and my best guess is I'm messing it up here:

```
if '2020' in line[34]
```

I thought originally that I didn't count the zero, so tried position 35 but it was out of range so I know I'm looking at the right column. Well, maybe I don't know because I can't figure this out.

EDIT:
I am not getting an exception. It's simply showing "Not Found". Example from that columns date format: 03/02/2020 (MM/DD/YYYY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want to copy/extract the lines containing `2020` from one file to another, you do not need to use the `csv` module and could process the input file line by line.

Since you did not provide any sample input data, I generated a very basic sample to be able to show the general approach. My sample file `Input.txt` looks like this:

```
1990 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
1996 - Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
2020 - Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes
2000 - nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec
1976 - pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
2020 - Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
2002 - In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
2000 - Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
2009 - Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
2003 - Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
1999 - Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
2010 - Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
1990 - Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
1983 - Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.
2020 - Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
2019 - Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus.
2016 - Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
2008 - Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh.
1973 - Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc
```

Assuming that the criterion you want to extract the data on is unique per line, you can neglect any column order or column structure and just look at the content of each line like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

INPUT_FILE_NAME = 'Input.txt'
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = 'Output.txt'

with open(INPUT_FILE_NAME, 'r') as input_file:
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if '2020' in line:
                output_file.write(line)
```

The extracted data is written to an output file `Output.txt` which will only contain lines with `2020` in it:

```
2020 - Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes
2020 - Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
2020 - Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
```